# Program(java) skips nextLine() prompt and continues with program

Tags: java

here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DriverProject1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int roomNumber;
    int numberOfRooms;
    int optionNumber;
    String guestName = null;
    String phoneNumber;
    int nightsStaying;
    double nightlyRate;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many rooms are in the hotel?");
    numberOfRooms = keyboard.nextInt();
    Hotel Carnegie = new Hotel(numberOfRooms);
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the MENU!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number corresponding to the option desired."); // main menu screen
        System.out.println("OPTION 1: Put guest into room");
        System.out.println("OPTION 2: Remove guest from room");
        System.out.println("OPTION 3: Get guest info");
        System.out.println("OPTION 4: Get guest count");
        System.out.println("OPTION 5: Display guest book");
        System.out.println("OPTION 6: Calculate expected income");
        System.out.println("OPTION 7: Quit");

        optionNumber = keyboard.nextInt(); // choosing an option
        if (optionNumber == 1) // if option 1 is chosen
        {

            System.out.println("What is the guests first name?");
            guestName = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the guests Phone number?");
            phoneNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
            Guest newGuest = new Guest(guestName);
            newGuest.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
```

"What is the guests first name? What is the guests Phone number?" appears and it will not take anything for the guest name. `guestName` has been initialized to "". lines 36 -39. not sure of the issue going on. i am using a few methods contained within my hotel class, however i am almost certain they do not contain the error which causes this bug. also the do loop is completed later on in the code.

Comment: -> Can you give us some more informations? I don't understand your problem

Comment: and what is the `keyboard`?

Comment: Are you using anything apart from `nextLine()` for example `nextInt()` , `nextDouble()` etc in your program?

Comment: guestName is taking a value, but it is not being assigned to the name of newGuest because it happens after the input is taken

Comment: when i run the program it prints the first two lines (What is the guests first name?   &   What is the guests Phone number?) . it does not stop to allow the user to enter a name for the guest.

Comment: @Will post your complete code which you are referring here.

Comment: skip a line after `nextInt()` because it doesnt consume the whole line

Comment: @Will - change the code as shown in my answer, then it will work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keyboard.nextLine();
guestName = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Skip a line by adding keyboard.nextLine(); before reading guestname. This works for me.

Answer (score -2):

change the code as shown below then it will work

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DriverProject1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int roomNumber;
    int numberOfRooms;
    int optionNumber;
    String guestName = null;
    String phoneNumber;
    int nightsStaying;
    double nightlyRate;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many rooms are in the hotel?");
    numberOfRooms = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
    Hotel Carnegie = new Hotel(numberOfRooms);
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the MENU!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number corresponding to the option desired."); // main menu screen
        System.out.println("OPTION 1: Put guest into room");
        System.out.println("OPTION 2: Remove guest from room");
        System.out.println("OPTION 3: Get guest info");
        System.out.println("OPTION 4: Get guest count");
        System.out.println("OPTION 5: Display guest book");
        System.out.println("OPTION 6: Calculate expected income");
        System.out.println("OPTION 7: Quit");

        optionNumber = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());; // choosing an option
        if (optionNumber == 1) // if option 1 is chosen
        {

            System.out.println("What is the guests first name?");
            guestName = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the guests Phone number?");
            phoneNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
            Guest newGuest = new Guest(guestName);
            newGuest.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
```

Comment: No change in the behavior